# Issues about Installing ROS on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos-mountain-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to install ROS on Mac OSX 10.8.1, following electric Homebrew Installation. And after fixing(hopefully) the boost lib problem, new one comes:

[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: unrecognized version: 10.8.1

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 16, in 
sys.exit(not rosinstall_main(sys.argv))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall/rosinstall_cli.py", line 228, in rosinstall_main
options.catkinpp)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosinstall/rosinstall_cmd.py", line 100, in cmd_generate_ros_files
subprocess.check_call("source %s && rosmake ros%s --rosdep-install%s" % (os.path.join(path, 'setup.sh'), ros_comm_insert, rosdep_yes_insert), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/Klinux/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1

I searched on google but didn't get any results, so could anybody help me out of this?
Thanks a lot...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43032/issues-about-installing-ros-on-mountain-lion/) by [Klinux](https://answers.ros.org/users/3143/klinux/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-09-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into a similar issue installing Fuerte.  Adding a version number for Mountain Lion to rospkg/os_detect.py:220 fixed the issue for me.

_osx_codename_map = {4: 'tiger',
5: 'leopard',
6: 'snow',
7: 'lion',
8: 'mountain lion'}

---

Originally posted by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) with karma: 395 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [david.hodo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1902/david.hodo/) on 2012-09-05**:
I'm not sure where that map is used in the rest of ROS so someone with more knowledge of the system than me might could comment on whether a space is acceptable in the os name.

**Comment by [Klinux](https://answers.ros.org/users/3143/klinux/) on 2012-09-06**:
thanks for your answer, actually after that I pass the making, strange though, but new problem comes out.... and I change to ubuntu.  so I cannot test if your suggestion does the trick or not. but thanks anyway.